# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined when I try and change Column name in Select Statement. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

When I use this I get the table perfectly fine:

```
Select B.bid, B.title, B.sellingprice, A.authid, A.sname, A.fname, AL.payrate  
From Book B
Inner Join Allocation AL
ON B.bid = AL.bid
Inner Join Author A
ON AL.authid = A.authid
Order by bid, authid;
```

But when I try and change columns like this it comes up with error:

```
Select B.bid as "Book ID", B.title as "Title", B.sellingprice as "Selling Price", A.authid as "Author ID", A.sname as "Surname", A.fname as "First Name", AL.payrate as "Payrate"  
From Book B
Inner Join Allocation AL
ON B.bid = AL.bid
Inner Join Author A
ON AL.authid = A.authid
Order by bid, authid;
```

ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: Your double quotes don't look like normal double quotes to me.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it. I accidentally copied the one that's on my assignment doc. It's changed the error message now to column ambiguously defined. Any idea what's causing this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify the column names in the `order by` clause with the appropriate table names:

```
Select B.bid as "Book ID", 
       B.title as "Title", 
       B.sellingprice as "Selling Price", 
       A.authid as "Author ID", 
       A.sname as "Surname", 
       A.fname as "First Name", 
       AL.payrate as "Payrate"  
  From Book B
 Inner Join Allocation AL
    ON B.bid = AL.bid
 Inner Join Author A
    ON AL.authid = A.authid
 Order by B.bid, A.authid;
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Why don't I have to do that for the top code but when I change column names I do?